# Unison shows error about locked archives

Tags: sync, unison

I have installed [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to sync data between my two PCs but I am getting an error about a non existing file. Here it is 
[image]
there is no such file in the .unison folder called lkb60...... which is being complained.

Comment: It might be a weird bug, have you asked the devs at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working!!!

Apparently, problem was that, Unison was not able to create a profile using the Unison-gtk (still don't know why it was showing error about a non-existing file) so due to this there was some problem loading the profile.

What I did now, I went into the .unison and created the profile by creating a profile.prf file consisting the info as follows-

```
root = /home/gaurav/
root = ssh://gaurav@192.168.0.3//home/gaurav/
```

Here is a complete How-To on the issue.
[http://www.micahcarrick.com/unison-synchronize-ubuntu.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20100714161325/http://www.micahcarrick.com/unison-synchronize-ubuntu.html) [Editor’s note: Links to archived version, as the original is not available anymore.]

Comment: Why wasn’t it able though? The permissions are OK, at least here. But I got the same problem. And I really don’t want to create a junk file that I will forget to delete. Also, the link is dead nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure that the file really dosen't exist (re-check the whole path) you may try deleting the `.unison` folder and remaking the settings you have right now...

Comment: already tried that, didn't help.

Comment: what happens when you delete that folder and restart?

Answer (score 0):

There’s another possible cause for this problem, as it was in my case:

You may be trying to sync to the same system! Say by trying to sync a local directory to the same one but via ssh.

Of course it then trips over its own profile/lock file that it just created or tried to create.

In my case this was caused by the two machines recently swapping roles and swapping IP addresses with it, but the host names not having been updated.